# Vue.js: Cannot hide a div with a sidebar with CSS media queries

Tags: html, css, vue.js, components, media-queries

I tried to hide a div with my sidebar with this method:

```
/* For mobile phones: */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
 .sidebar {
  display: none!important;
 }
}

/* For tablets */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .sidebar {
  display: none!important;
 }
}
```

The sidebar listens to these rules but it seems like the content is disappearing but the `<div>` is actually staying. It might be like this because `<div>` with the sidebar is actually a component. But then I don't know how to solve it.

My page:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <sidebar />
  <main-content/>
 </div>
</template>
```

The sidebar component:

```
<template>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <div class="logo"><img src="../../../components/img/logo.svg"/></div>
      <a href="#" id="title">System</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <!--<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href="#">News and events</a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>-->
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="nav-icon" src="../../../components/img/users.svg" />Users</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Import</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Invitation</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a href="#">Organisation</a></li>-->
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="nav-icon" src="../../../components/img/polls.svg" />Poll</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: is the css scoped ? in which component is the css placed ?

Comment: CSS works perfectly regarding other parts of my page. I placed this in the assets folder and imported this in my `app.vue` file, the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your component styles are `scoped`. See the [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) how it works.

---

A posible solution is to move the style block to the component itself:

```
<template>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <div class="logo"><img src="../../../components/img/logo.svg"/></div>
      <a href="#" id="title">System</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="nav-icon" src="../../../components/img/users.svg" />Users</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Import</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Invitation</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="nav-icon" src="../../../components/img/polls.svg" />Poll</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* For mobile phones: */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
 .sidebar {
  display: none !important;
 }
}

/* For tablets */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .sidebar {
  display: none !important;
 }
}
</stlyle>
```

> Another solution is to declare a non `scoped` `style` block, this usually goes in your `App.vue` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in CSS for a container with main content. It had left margin, so when the sidebar disappeared, it stayed at the same place, not taking the width of the removed sidebar.